# Displaying data from SQLite as a text in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, button

I have a table in SQLite with some data in it (e.g. NAME, AGE, GENDER).I want to display all the NAME's as a text in the button and also it should be able to automatically create buttons according to the number of items (NAME).

I want to do this is because I want to display the rest of the data using a different .xml file. For instance, the names are JONE, KEN, PEN so when the user clicks on JONE, it should display his name, age and gender only.

Please help...

Comment: did you try anything

Comment: Show us the effort/research you put in this, what code you already tried. Then, we would be able to answer specific questions. Your question is way too broad

Answer (score -1):

this will work

```
// Getting All Contacts
public ArrayList<Contact> Get_Contacts() {
try {
contact_list.clear();

// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
// Adding contact to list
contact_list.add(contact);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return contact list
cursor.close();
db.close();
return contact_list;
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
}

return contact_list;
}
```